# QML Listview in QMLProfiler reporting twice delegate creation

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt5

Here is an simple ListView with just 10 items. When i ran QMLProfiler for this application, the stats Shows that the number of calls made to create the delegate are twice. Could someone explain is this behavior?

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    ListView{
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 10
        delegate: Rectangle{
            width: parent.width
            height: 60
            Text {
                id: name
                text: qsTr("Item is ") + index
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found from the Qt bug report [QML Profiler shows double amount of Repeater delegate Create calls](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69921)
 which tells the following:

> Object creation typically happens in two stages, which are counted
>   separately in the profiler.
>
> Each object creation involves one creation phase and one callback to
>   componentComplete(). Those are tracked separately.